# Shadow appearing on page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to structure a media query and for some reason the page is creating a shadow when my mouse is hovering anywhere on the page. It is only doing it on a desktop with the window scaled down to a viewport of 640 or below.

I am referring to this shadow line under the blue container:

[image]

This can be seen live at :

http://optimumwebdesigns.com/contact

I believe the cause is a container I have, `contact_arrow_box` . The code for it is this:

```
.contact_arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #88b7d5;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
.contact_arrow_box:after, .contact_arrow_box:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.contact_arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-right-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.contact_arrow_box:before {
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-top: -36px;  
}
```

My media query alteration for this container:

```
.contact_arrow_box {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.contact_arrow_box:after, .contact_arrow_box:before {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
}
.contact_arrow_box:after {
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.contact_arrow_box:before {
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Does anyone see the cause for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the culprit

```
.no-touch:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Disable or overwrite it to remove the box-shadow effect

Comment: Yes, it was! Do you have any idea why I have whitespace past the full `width: 100%`?

Comment: I dont see any whitespace. Have you checked it with chrome screen simulator?

Comment: Yes. In the media query, to the far white there is whitespace. I have been trying to figure it out for some time and I don't see what is causing it.

Comment: I found `.mobile-header` has `padding: 0 2%;` Remove or overwrite it

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!